# Continuous column lines in tables with enumerate

Tags: tables, enumerate, columns

I would like to have some assistance on how to make these column lines continuous after enumerate?. My code is

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
\footnotesize
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{9cm} |p{0.12\textwidth} |p{0.10\textwidth} |p{0.05\textwidth}|}\hline
    \hline
 \textbf{a) Resource } & \CheckmarkBold & 1-5 & {}\\
 \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item Divine 
\item  Nestled  
\item   Ministry 
 \end{enumerate}\\\hline 

 \textbf{a) Community} & \CheckmarkBold & 1-5 & {}\\
 \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]

\item  Life

 \end{enumerate}\\\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

A compilable, though not exactly minimal, example:

```
\documentclass[preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{bm,array}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{subfigure}
%\usepackage{lineno}
%\linenumbers
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{framed} % Framing content
\usepackage{multicol} % Multiple columns environment
\biboptions{sort&compress} %compresses numerical citations
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;} 

\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % to change header and footers
\usepackage{blindtext} % to quickly get a full document
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}%
 \rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}   
}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\footnotesize
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{9cm} |p{0.12\textwidth} |p{0.10\textwidth} |p{0.05\textwidth}|}\hline
    \hline
 \textbf{a) Resource } & \CheckmarkBold & 1-5 & {}\\
 \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item Divine 
\item  Nestled  
\item   Ministry 
 \end{enumerate}\\\hline 
 \textbf{a) Community} & \CheckmarkBold & 1-5 & {}\\
 \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item  Life
 \end{enumerate}\\\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please post a compilable example, not just disrupted fragments bitten out of a document ;-)

Comment: Don't load packages multiple times, e.g. `amssymb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `&&&` -- three columns of "nothingness" -- after each `\end{enumerate}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}
%%% I've trimmed the preamble down to the bare essentials
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}%
 \rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}   
}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\footnotesize
\centering % not "\begin{center}" and "\end{center}"
\begin{tabular}{|p{9cm} |p{0.12\textwidth} |
                 p{0.10\textwidth} |p{0.05\textwidth}|}
\hline
\textbf{a) Resource } & \CheckmarkBold & 1--5 & \\
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item Divine 
\item  Nestled  
\item   Ministry 
\end{enumerate} &&&\\ % <--- note "&&&"
\hline 
 \textbf{a) Community} & \CheckmarkBold & 1--5 & \\
 \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item  Life
 \end{enumerate}&&&\\ % <--- note "&&&"
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```